Solution of commutator system and its application
I was asked in a research project to find a set of operators $B$ on infinite dimensional Hilbert Space $H$, that satisfy the following commutator system $(\Sigma)$:
$$[A,B] = C,$$
$$[A,C] = 0,$$
$$[B,C] = 0,$$
where A is a given linear operators on $H$, $C$ is non-zero operators. It can be observed that the operators ( A ) and ( B ) generate a second-degree nilpotent Lie algebra.
Using linear algebra and spectral theory, we can obtain many solutions to $(\Sigma)$ depending on the state of the operator (A).
The problem: I want to find a practical example or application that relies heavily on solving systems as $(\Sigma)$.
Thanks.

As you said, representations of the Heisenberg Lie algebra have many applications in physics.

The Stone-von Neumann theorem is an important example in the foundations of quantum mechanics and also has purely mathematical applications, e.g. it can be used to construct what is called the oscillator representation of the metaplectic group, generalize the Fourier transform, various other things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem
